# Quartz: Undesired multiple job run in same time

Tags: quartz-scheduler, jobs, quartz.net, job-scheduling, quartz

I have some jobs that run with their schedule, but when I have for example two jobs that run in same time Quartz start one of this jobs two or three times. Did someone have the same problem? And how can I resolve this?

Comment: Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure, but there could be copule reasons,

1). you are creating a new scheduler instance everytime you trigger/schedule  job

2). or you are running the same exact Execute method of a class or have same job running eveytime.

So, when you declare your scheduler, instead of working on some other instance of **scheduler**, use default scheduler all time, for e.g.,

```
private IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
```

that is what I have done and I have a lot notifications/jobs triggering using Quartz.Net and haven't faced any issue yet.

Let me know if any of this helps. Cheers!